# QTableWidget becomes slow for large tables

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, qtablewidget

I want to create a Qt table widget which adds about 20 new rows per second (maxed at 10000). Old rows are never changed.

Ar first I used QTableWidget, but I see the CPU% increases as the table size increases, and gets to 100% at around 1000 rows total.

So I tried to create my own model, which only does `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRows` every 5 seconds. I hoped that the CPU% will become constant since I only emit the **new** rows, but I see that it still climbs up to 100%.

So I checked the number of `data()` calls I'm getting between emits, and I saw that is equal to about **240 * total_num_rows**.

1. Why does the view query **all** of the rows and not just the new ones?
2. Why 240? I have 10 columns total per row. Are there 24 Roles?
3. Can I control the view somehow to do less queries (constant)?

## Edit

#### Item view:

```
''' How to display each item '''
class BindedItemView(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self._data = item
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _text(self, index):
        return QVariant()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _font(self, index):
        return QVariant()

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _background(self, index):
        return QVariant()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _foreground(self, index):
        return QVariant()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
    def get(self, role, col):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._text(col)
        if role == Qt.FontRole:
            return self._font(col)
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            return self._foreground(col)
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            return self._background(col)             
        return QVariant()
```

#### Model:

```
class BindedTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    
    end_of_process_signal = pyqtSignal()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def __init__(self, headers, item_view):
        super(BindedTableModel, self).__init__()
        self._headers = headers
        self._item_view = item_view
        self._items = []
        self._last_row_count = 0
        self._num_data_requests = 0
        
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#

    def _index(self, item):
        return self._items.index(item)
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _indexSorted(self, item):
        return bisect.bisect(self._items, item)
   
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _refreshView(self):
        row_count = len(self._items)
        print "DATA REQUESTS: %u" % self._num_data_requests
        self._num_data_requests = 0
        if self._last_row_count < row_count:
            print "INSERT ROWS: %u %u" % (self._last_row_count, row_count - 1)
            self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self._last_row_count, row_count - 1)
            self.endInsertRows()
#         elif self._last_row_count > row_count:
#             self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row_count, self._last_row_count - 1)
#             self.endRemoveRows()
#         else:
#             top_left = self.createIndex(0, 0)
#             bottom_right = self.createIndex(row_count - 1, self.columnCount() - 1)
#             self.dataChanged.emit(top_left, bottom_right)
        self._last_row_count = row_count
        
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _onUpdate(self):
        pass 
        
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def _addItem(self, item, pos):
        self._items.insert(pos, item)
        self._onUpdate()
            
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
    def _removeItem(self, pos):
        self._items.pop(pos)
        self._onUpdate()
        
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def appendItem(self, item):
        self._addItem(item, len(self._items))

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def addItemSorted(self, item):
        self._addItem(item, self._indexSorted(item))

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
    def removeItem(self, item):
        self._removeItem(self._index(item))
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
        
    def clear(self):
        self._items = []
        
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def refreshView(self):
        self._refreshView()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    '''
    Override 
    '''
    def rowCount(self, parent = None):
        return len(self._items)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#

    '''
    Override 
    '''
    def columnCount(self, parent = None):
        return len(self._headers)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    '''
    Override 
    '''
    def data(self, index, role):
        self._num_data_requests += 1
        item = self._items[index.row()]
        view = self._item_view(item)
        return view.get(role, index.column())
                
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
            
    '''
    Override 
    '''            
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._headers[section] 
        return QVariant()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#

    '''
    Override 
    '''    
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            pass

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self._items.__iter__()
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._items
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand the problem if you post your model's code.

Comment: @vahancho Thanks. Posted code.

Comment: @JonHarper User custom. The user needs to make sure it has __gt__ __lt__ and __eq__.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround, but limiting the model to `row count < 1000` gives a constant CPU%.

So an elegant solution for me will be to create a "paged" table view, which only shows N rows at a time (and the user can control the currently displayed window).

This yields excellent CPU as well as better usability, so I think the original question is not relevant.