# Slow PyQt5 QAbstractTableModel for Pandas Model with qTableview

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

i am using PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel) to show  data in a  qtableView. it's working fine with less data. but whenever i tried with large datas it became slow. for 5000 rows data it almost took 20-25 seconds .it just take a seconds in mssql mgmt studio to run the  query. i am not getting where i did wrong with my codes.

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]+1
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))
        

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role != QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
            return False
        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
            return False
        self._data.values[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

i tried many approaches like st the chunksize , but not working. please help me out

```
sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' +
                          server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
cursor = sql_conn.cursor()

def loadTranForACC(AccountID):
    query_string="Select * from  user.dbo.Transaction(nolock) where accID =" + AccountID
    data=pd.read_sql_query(query_string, sql_conn)
    return data
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with the data from Database, I'd like to point out that PyQt has
[`QSqlTableModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlTableModel.html#qsqltablemodel) and [`QSqlQueryModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtSql/QSqlQueryModel.html) to work with the data from database.

Looking at your model, to me, the model looks fine, try to see exactly what part of your program is eating up time.

You can look at these threads for more information and details regarding these:

[qtablewidget becomes slow for large tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529047/qtablewidget-becomes-slow-for-large-tables)

[pyqt qtablewidget extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081852/pyqt-qtablewidget-extremely-slow)

The ultimate solution though would be to use **pagination**, show only 500,1000 rows at a time, it will run within a fraction of seconds.

You can visit these threads to implement pagination: [QT Forum | Pagination in QTableWidget](https://forum.qt.io/topic/70095/pagination-in-qtablewidget) or [Paginated Display of Table Data in PyQt](https://sateeshkumarb.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/paginated-display-of-table-data-in-pyqt/)

Comment: Thank you for  your comment, but i think problem is in my model.  because from 'data=pd.read_sql_query(query_string, sql_conn)'  i got datas very quickely. it becomes slow whenever model tried to show datas in 'tableView'.
and i don't want to use pagination  in my app.